# finding max catches if you can move at a certain speed while objects appear at particular timestamps?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I faced this problem in an interview, I couldn't solve it in interview.
I recall a similair problem that i solved during IOI though cannot recall it.

Given N houses in a line.
each of M pokemon makes an appearance at a house exactly once.
ex - a pokemon appears for an instant at 5th house at time = 6.
another pokemon appears for an instant at 7th house at time = 1.
and so on.

we start at house P, we can move at speed of X house/sec. find max number of pokemon you can catch?

All i can think of is greedy or bruteforce but bruteforce is exponential and greedy is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Observation**: Each Pokemon disappears right after they appear, so we need to be at a house at time=x to catch the Pokemon. If we can not make it in time, we never stop there.

**Solution**: create a new directed graph *G=(V,A)* where each *v_i in V* represents a house *h_i = house(v_i)* where a Pokemon appears at time *t(v_i)*.
Create *A* containing arc *u->v*, for each such pair if *t(u)+distance(house(u),house(v)) =< t(v)*. In other words: if it is possible to catch Pokemon at at house(v) after Pokemon at house(u), given the time constraints.

Create a root *s* of the [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) and create an arc *s->u* for *u in V* if *distance(P, house(u)) <= t(u)*.

Now, for example, with a depth-first search, you can find the longest path and reconstruct the route you take in the original instance.

Comment: This will fail for some cases right. For example, it might be possible to ignore ith theif even if we can catch him, because if we choose him, we might lose subsequent set of theifs.

Comment: I don't understand, I don't see it. The constructed DAG captures all possible moves from one pokemon/house to any other. Well, it is not acyclic if for any two vertices u,v: t(v)==t(u) and distance(house(v), house(u))==0. But this is not a problem as we can find the longest path without cycles the same way in a cyclic graph.

Comment: A prove would sound like that: 
If you have a path *p* from *s* to *u* in the DAG --> you will catch all pokemon at *house(w)* for each *w in p*, by construction of the DAG. 
Assume their is a valid sequence of moves between houses and pokemon catches greater that the longest path in the DAG, therefore it is not a path in the DAG, then there have to be two sequential pokemon catches u and v that violates conditions of in creation of the DAG. But if any conditions are violated there is no sequence of moves that catch pokemon v after pokemon u before time t(v). Contradiction.

Comment: Actually, if the resulting graph would be really cyclic you will have a problem, as longest path is NP-hard. This would only happen if instead, for each Pokemon a time window *[t1,t2]* is given of appearing and disappearing. Modeling that yields a general directed graph and it becomes hard to solve.